# Push ids in an array in react

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I want to save an array of object ids in the database but it receives as a plain string from the frontend. the useState hook: `const [package_ids, setPackage_Ids] = useState([]);` I am appending this ids in the formdata: `formData.append("package_ids", package_ids);` The code where admin selects the packageIds:

```
<Form.Group controlId="package_ids">
   <Form.Label>Select Package/s:</Form.Label>
   {packages.map((item) => (
     <Form.Check
       key={item._id}
       type="checkbox"
       label={item.name}
       onChange={(e) =>
         setPackage_Ids((c) =>
           e.target.checked
            ? [...c, item._id]
            : c.filter((el) => el !== item._id)
         )
       }
     />
   ))}
</Form.Group>
```

If I log the packageids in the front-end it logs as an array and in the backend I am using `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: can you provide more details ?
like what you get in backend
what you get in frontend 
what is expect in front and back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send an array/object to form data directly. Form data only receives primitive data types like number or string.

In this case, you can use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to string-typed data.

```
formData.append("package_ids", JSON.stringify(package_ids));
```

Your server will receive `package_ids` as a string, so you need to parse it back to your original data by

```
const originalData = JSON.parse(package_ids);
```

---

If you are concerned that the above approach makes your data hard to read, you also can use the string [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) (for the client-side) and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) (for the server-side)

Client-side

```
const packageIds = package_ids.join(",") //"1,2,3"
```

Server-side

```
const packageIds = package_ids.split(",") //["1","2","3"]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73864232/19773515 here is the another question regarding the file upload in MERN. can you please guide me there?